# JSF Delete entity on DataTable with p:dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm currently working on a CRUD form and is now working on the last part which should be the most easiest - delete. But I want to show a dialog before the user can do the actual deletion. And this is where I'm having problem with Primefaces 3.4. For some reason I cannot set the action in the button inside the p:dialog, ajax=false failed. So here's what I did:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msgs['action.delete']}"
                    styleClass="a-center">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
        oncomplete="confirmation.show()">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
            target="#{marketingCodeBean.marketingCode}" value="#{code}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

The Dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                message="#{msgs['message.marketingCode.confirmDelete']}"
                header="#{msgs['common.confirmDelete']}" severity="alert"
                widgetVar="confirmation">
    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="#{msgs['common.yes']}"
        oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" update=":form:mktgCodeTable"
        actionListener="#{marketingCodeBean.remove}" />
    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="#{msgs['common.no']}"
        onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I'm aware that the actionListener should not be use for business action, but I can't think of a workaround given the datatable and the dialog. Any idea on how I can make ajax=false in p:commandButton inside p:confirmDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once rendered, the dialog's HTML output is by some onload JavaScript relocated to end of HTML `<body>` in order to achieve the best cross-browser compatible overlay/positioning. However, this thus means that if it was placed inside a `<form>`, it would not be in a `<form>` anymore and synchronous (non-ajax) requests would then not work anymore. This is not exactly an `action` vs `actionListener` issue.

The `<p:dialog>` (and `<p:confirmDialog>` as you seem to be actually using) should have its own `<h:form>` component.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable>
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
...
<p:confirmDialog>
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: You're right I forgot to create a separate form for the p:confirmDialog and included it in the main form. Thanks again. But I wonder why it won't work with a single form?

Comment: Because the HTML output of the dialog is by JavaScript relocated to end of HTML `<body>`, causing it not be inside any `<form>` anymore.